# Multiplication of the projection matrix with a vector

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus, projection

Suppose that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are each $n \times 1$ vectors and $X_1$ and  $X_2$ are columns of $X$ so that $X$ is $n \times 2$. Suppose that $P_X = X(X'X)^{-1}X'$ is the projection matrix. I need to prove that $P_X X_2 = X_2$. I attempted to prove this. I seem to have two proofs but I am not happy with them.

In the first proof I simply carry out the matrix algebra $P_X X_2$ and this gives me $X_2$. But I do not like this proof because it involves the very tedious calculation of taking the inverse of $X'X$.

In the second proof I start with $X(X'X)^{-1}X'X_2 = X_2$ and pre-multiply both sides of the equation by $X(X'X)^{-1}X'$ which gives $X(X'X)^{-1}X'X(X'X)^{-1}X'X_2 = X(X'X)^{-1}X'X_2$. This simplifies to $X(X'X)^{-1}X'X_2 = X(X'X)^{-1}X'X_2$ which shows that the equality holds. But I am not sure if this is a proof.

Are these proofs plausible? And is there a better proof?

Comment: Since $P_X$ is the projection matrix we have $P_XX_2=X_2$. Maybe you want prove that $P_X$ is the projection matrix onto $span(X_1,X_2)$?.

Comment: Can we from $A\vec{v}=A\vec{u}$ conclude $\vec{v}=\vec{u}?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X_2$ is the second column of $X$ then $X_2 = X\left[ \begin{array}{c} 0 \\ 1 \end{array} \right],$ so $X(X'X)^{-1}X'X_2 = X(X'X)^{-1}X'X\left[ \begin{array}{c} 0 \\ 1 \end{array} \right]$ and you get a cancellation that leaves only $X \left[ \begin{array}{c} 0 \\ 1 \end{array} \right],$ which is $X_2.$

Comment: A neat proof. Thanks.

Comment: @Snoopy : I'm glad you like it. Remember that you can "accept" the answer.

Comment: @Snoopy : There should be a check mark below the number of votes on the answer.